# pane.getChildren().addAll(); not working in a scene javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

This code will not allow the line to draw in my window... All I have in the fxml file is a simple pane with the fx:id of hi to test things out. There is no error, the line simply doesn't appear. I've also tried this with a box and circle. I really need help, this is an important project.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class PlotSceneController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    Pane hi;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    Line line = new Line(0,0,10,110);
        line.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        line.setStrokeWidth(10);
        hi.getChildren().addAll(line);

    }

}
```

FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane fx:id="hi" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-
Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>

</children>
</Pane>
```

Main Class, leads to another page with a button that leads to the page I'm having trouble with.

```
public class Main extends Application {

Stage firstStage;
Scene loginButton;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {             

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    firstStage = primaryStage;                  
    loginButton = new Scene(root, 900, 700);    

    primaryStage.setTitle("Treatment Data");            
    primaryStage.setScene(loginButton);         
    primaryStage.show();                        
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        //Main class
    launch(args);                       //Launches application/window
}
```

}

Comment: Post the rest of the application (the FXML file and application class). Do you get any errors when you run it?

Comment: @James_D Updated it to include more info about my issue and more code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missed to set a controller class PlotSceneController.java. Set controller class in different two way like using main class setController() method or set controller class in left bottom side controller pane in scene Builder screen.

**Using Main**

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
loader.setController(new PlotSceneController());
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
```

**Or Using FXML**

Set Controller class with full package path like below way

[image]

Comment: That's so ridiculously simple, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot!